# How to make h1, h2 seem to like normal paragraph text

Tags: html, css

How do you make the h1, h2 seem like standard text?

For example, I want the word 'standard' in the sentence above be a H1 on my page... I can make it the same size, issue is it makes a new line and margin etc...

Comment: Apply the same CSS rules to `h1` and `h2` as you are to `p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements are block level. Change them to inline so they don't occupy full width.

```
    p, h1{
        display:inline; 
        font-size:1em; 
        font-weight:normal;
    }

    <h1>hello</h1>
    <p>there</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

set this in your CSS file (or tag).
play with the font sizes and such in order to set proper text size and color.

```
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just style it in CSS:

```
.your_class h1{
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:400;
    margin:0; // if You use for example bootstrap
    padding:0; // if You use for example bootstrap
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Only one thing; it still makes it's own line... it doesn't blend into a paragraph?

Comment: @Matt1966 Those are heading elements. You shouldn't be using them to blend into paragraphs. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @rob Just an experiment I'm running :) Is there a way?

Comment: That's the rule of HTML. You can of course set inline styles for both, but it's not right and probably You will see validation error: ... The <p> tag can only contain inline elements. The header tags are block-level elements, and cannot go inside <p> tags even when you style them to display inline ...

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend your font-size is 14px for the entire page. Change the h1 font-size to that and apply 0px line-height. This is the closest I was able to get.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Edit: I didn't add bold because I am assuming you wish to keep the default font-weight applied by h1.

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanted to make the word "standard" a different size to the rest of the text try wrapping it in a span and then give the span an id and edit it from CSS to be a larger size